# Word VSTO Add-In : Deleting GroupContentControl

Tags: .net, ms-word, vsto

I'm working on my first Word VSTO add-in. Among other things, I need it to make certain paragraphs read-only, but not permanently. I'm trying to use GroupContentControls (GCC's for short) at runtime to that effect.

I've got GCC creation down pat : that was easy, I just use the example on MSDN. However, I can't seem to be able to delete a GCC.

Here's the code I've tried :

```
// Get a VSTO document object
Document doc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument); 
// Find the GCC in the document, by its ID
var controls = from GroupContentControl g in doc.Controls
               where g.ID.Equals(gcc_ID)
               select g;
// Safety check
if (controls == null)
    return;
if (controls.Count() == 0)
    return;
// Delete the GCC
var gc = controls.First();
gc.Delete(false);
```

For brevity's sake I'm only listing the code that doesn't work. The rest of the add-in is designed in such a way that this code only runs when the active Word document contains a GroupContentControl with an ID that matches gcc_ID.

I get three types of bug at run time :

- The code runs without a hitch but the GCC is still in place, leading me to believe one of my safety tests tripped and the code returned prematurely
- The code hangs at the Delete call with an exception that says gc is not a GroupContentControl.
- Early in my debugging I also had an exception on the gc variable assignment because "controls" was "null"... which was weird because the safety test just before didn't trip. But I don't seem to be able to reproduce that specific outcome.

Is there a simpler and better method for deleting a GroupContentControl, knowing its ID ? I'm fairly new to .NET and very new to VSTO, I may be missing something very obvious to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging this kind of thing, the first step is to work with the "native" Word objects (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) and make sure everything at that level is working fine.

If you don't need the VSTO objects, don't use them - stick with the native objects. It's not clear to me at all why you'd need a VSTO GroupContentControl object - as far as I know, there's no special VSTO functionality for a group content control.

Be that as it may, if you need the VSTO objects in an add-in, at run-time, you have to create them - every single time your add-in runs. The following code does that. You should start with the *native* Word document because you're going to need that, later on.

Then create a VSTO document object from the native Word document. You basically have that, but should start from the native object instead of going back to Globals...ActiveDocument. Note that my code differs slightly from yours in this respect since I'm targeting a different .NET Framework. You should continue to use `Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject...`

The next step is to get the native group content control. Since you have a static ID and you want to retrieve only one content control just address it directly without lamdas, or collections or anything else: `doc.ContentControls[gcc_ID];`

From the native content control you can add a VSTO content control of type GroupContentControl. This object is dynamic and will *not* be retained in the document (or anywhere else) once the add-in goes out-of-scope.

From this point on, you should be OK.

```
    private void btnGroupCC_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        // Get a VSTO document object
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document VSTOdoc = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Extensions.DocumentExtensions.GetVstoObject(doc);
        // Find the GCC in the document, by its ID
        string gcc_ID = "778611894";
        Word.ContentControl cc = doc.ContentControls[gcc_ID];
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.GroupContentControl gcc = VSTOdoc.Controls.AddGroupContentControl(cc, "groupCC");
        // Safety check
        if (gcc == null)
            MessageBox.Show("no group cc");

        // Delete the GCC

        gcc.Delete(false);
    }
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386200.aspx#runtimeaddin, the topic about adding content controls at run-time.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm new to Office add-in programming (it's my first time ever), so I may not use the correct words : what I really need is to create and delete a GroupContentControl, I only use the term "VSTO" to refer to the type of add-in I'm programming. In other words, I don't have a requirement to use a VSTO object if a native object will work. I'm also new to C# and .NET so I don't understand the reason why my way of getting the VSTO document object differs from yours. You're assigning it to an intermediate variable ("doc") and I don't, but I don't get what difference it makes.

Comment: I've tried the code in your answer, and it appears to work in that a previously-locked paragraph can be edited again. But if I try to then lock that paragraph again, by creating a new GroupContentControl with the same name, I get this exception : 

Microsoft.Office.Tools.ControlNameAlreadyExistsException: 'The control cannot be added because a control with the name "Group_CC" already exists in the Controls collection.'

So I don't know if the GCC is really deleted...

Comment: Further experimentation reveals that if I delete the GroupContentControl, then save the document and quit Word, then reopen both, I can add a new GroupContentControl with the same name as the one I deleted. However, if I try to do that delete / add "cycle" during the same Word session I will get the exception "name already exists". I know that ContentControl names are runtime-only and not saved in the document itself, so it seems deleting a content control only deletes it from the document, its name still exists in Word. I'm thinking this may be related to Word's "Undo" stack, am I right ?

Comment: I finally got to a solution that does what I need : I simply generate a unique name any time I want to add a GroupContentControl, using DateTime.Now and a random number. I only store the ID of the GCC and use that to find it again when I need to delete it. I will soon be answering my own question with the relevant code.

Comment: Your confusion stems from the fact that you haven't read through the VSTO documentation in any depth - not even the reference link I gave you. VSTO *extends* the capabilities of the native Word objects: you can do everything the Word "interop" provides, plus a few things more. VSTO "wraps" the native control in order to provide the extensions. In this case, it's creating a "virtual" VSTO object wrapped around the native object. This information is cached during run-time, so you can't re-use the name. It's lost when the VSTO add-in goes out of scope, which is why the name works again, later.

Comment: I read that article while _learning_ to programming my add-in, I've only come to SO once I couldn't find the information I needed on MSDN. And at least in my experience, the difference between the native and VSTO objects is not exactly clearly explained. My job is microcontroller firmware, so there are lots of software engineering subtleties I don't find obvious. That's no reason to accuse me of not "reading the f... manual" ;-)

Comment: I didn't say *that*, but 1) SO isn't a tutorial site and your questions require a tutorial (or reading the documentation **in-depth**) and 2) the basics are in the Answer I wrote. The questions certainly can't be addressed adequately in a Comment. My advice was (and is) to NOT use the VSTO objects in this case, but the underlying native Word interop, for the reason given in the Answer.

Comment: I'm fairly new to SO, as you can see. I did try to look for tutorials but didn't find much (if you have any links, they are welcome). I understand you've been working on Office automation for over 20 years. I've been at it for 20 _days_ and sometimes I don't even know the correct _words_ to put in my search terms when I have a problem. And it's not like the official documentation is even complete. Take the "Active Document Change" event, for example : it triggers in quite a few situations that are not listed on its MSDN page and that I had to discover through experimentation.

Comment: If you really want to get into VSTO then the book by Eric Carter and Eric Lippert is pretty much "the" book. Beyond that, the older posts (from the days when the VSTO team were active) in the MSDN VSTO forum cover a lot of ground. And start with VBA for new things in the object model - if VBA can do it, VSTO can do it (with some exceptions such as keyboard shortcuts), using the same objects. There's a lot more info for VBA! Only use the VSTO object extensions if you explicitly need something they can do that Word can't (such as data-binding a content control to a custom task pane).

Comment: Back to your first Q in comments: I define `doc` because I need it again for `doc.ContentControls[gcc_ID];` Querying the Word interop is "expensive", so everything you can cache in a variable saves time/resources. `doc` and `cc` are the native objects. You should be able to do what you need with only these - the lines with `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.` are not needed to simply remove (and later recreate) the GroupContentControl.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. I think I got what I came for, my code now works and it's simpler than my first attempt. I guess I'm at a point with learning .NET where I can tell that I'm doing something wrong by the fact that my code looks too complicated for what it's meant to do. When I used LINQ to find a GCC by its ID, for example, it really felt that there had to be a simpler way, but reading the MSDN pages for the ContentControls and Controls collections really didn't make it clear I could just use the ID like an array index. I didn't even know which collection to use. Too bad I don't VBA :-(

Comment: Regarding the book you mentioned, it was written for Office 2007 and I'm using Office 2016. Is it still applicable ? To what extent ?

Comment: @JeanRoch The book is still applicable - the VSTO technology wasn't extended after after Office 2010 and in its essentials is still the same. RE VBA: that's your best entry point into the object models - by recording macros to see what object, methods and properties are used to accomplish something. Consider it a research tool.